# Devexpress grid column masking issue

Tags: .net, devexpress

We have a Devexpress grid column and have provided masking to it as follows :

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="gcQuantity" Caption="Quantity" Width="100" VisibleIndex="10" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
    <PropertiesTextEdit DisplayFormatString="N2"  MaskSettings-Mask="<0..999999999>.<0..99>" Width="100%" MaskSettings-AllowMouseWheel="false">
    </PropertiesTextEdit>
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

In Numeric masks Pressing the Up-Arrow and Down-Arrow keys increments or decrements the digit, And if value is zero and we press down key it will show highest value(in this case it shows 99999999).

We want to avoid this, if value is zero then even if user presses down key it should show zero.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
        DisplayFormatString="N2"  MaskSettings-Mask="<0..>.<0..99>"
```

or

```
          DisplayFormatString="N"  MaskSettings-Mask="<0..>.<0..99>"
```

or

```
     DisplayFormatString="N2"  MaskSettings-Mask="<0..999>.<0..>"
```

and then tell me

Comment: use one dot `.` instead of two `..`

Comment: or only `0` no dot

Comment: in the one which has just 0, right? or the one with 0 & 99?

Comment: yes you only have to set max and min values with 2 dots may be they are creating problem . so you try to set 0 repeat process debug if not then wait for others to answer